# Visual Studio 2010 only shows the first of "could not find file" - how to get whole list?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm using VS 2010. I've just made changes to a large number of files in a project. About 40 or so files got deleted. I checked out the entire project first (using Team Foundation 2012 as our source control). Now when trying to check in, I see an error "Could not find file 'C:\folder\filename.dll'" in a popup dialog. This is the first missing file it came across. When I check the Output window, I only see that one file. I know there are several others.

Visual Studio 2012 will display the list of all of the missing files in the Output window.

Is there a way to do this in VS 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this in Team Explorer 2010. Due to feedback this behaviour was changed in Visual Studio 2012.

Note: Visual Studio 2010 drops out of mainstream support in July.

Answer (score 0):

I would try command line first, tf checkin, posdibly with /i (not to prompt) and /validate (to not risk actual checkin).
Other, very basic solution is to get list of all checked out files(tf status) and write a script that undo checkout if file does not exist.